# What is the notation for set of prime factors of a number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

Is there a  notation for the set of prime factors of a number, or set of factors of a number?

Comment: Essentially, $\operatorname{Spec} \mathbb{Z}/(n)$.

Comment: $\pi(n)$  is used in *The Theory of Finite Groups* by Kurzweil & Stellmacher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really. Feel free to introduce your own notation at the beginning of whatever you're writing!